# Create Chart based on the list items

Tags: web-part

I have a list on the basis of which i want to design chart. As i have no idea how charts are developed in SharePoint, any kind of lead will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following ways to create charts using the data stored in your list:

1. Export list data to excel and create charts using Excel
   (Ref: http://www.sharethepoint.com/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-export-to-excel/)
2. Use a Javascript library to create charts using data stored in your list
   (Ref:http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blog/2013/05/building_charts_ins)